# How can I align my text/border to the center of my page with the <div> element?

Tags: html

```css
div1 {
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: Candara;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     width: auto;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div1 style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">
    <b>Text here</b>
  </div1>
</body>
```

I'm trying to align both my border and text to the center of my page, but somethings not working. If I haven't explained it well enough please ask for more details :). Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div1 style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">
    <b>Text here</b>
  </div1>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div1 {
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: Candara;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     width: auto;
 }
```

Comment: hey, can you explain, how it is behaving now and what you expected it to behave like?

Comment: What is `div1`? It does not exist. Use `div class="div1"` instead and in your css use `.div1`.

Comment: @BhuwanChandra I'm not very good at explaining but I'm trying to align both the border, and text inside the border to the top, and center of the page. At the moment it's stuck on the top, left hand side of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify `div1` to `div` and check again.

See below codes:

```css
div {
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: Candara;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     width: auto;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">
    <b>Text here</b>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have some mistake in your code the tag name is `div` no `div1` like you have there, if you change that you might see the result that you'r looking for! 
I hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to set width to your `body` tag and horizontal margin to auto to you text
also change your `div1` to `div`

```
body{
     width: 100vw;
}
div {
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: Candara;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: auto 10px;
     width: fit-content;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div1>` isn't a valid HTML element. Always use `<div>` and if you want to differentiate between your divs you can add an `id="div1"` or  `class="div1"` attribute. If your component should be re-usable (multiple times on the page), then use `class`. Otherwise use `id` (which should be unique).

I created a `div.div1` selector, which selects all elements that are a `<div>` element with the `.div1` class attribute (`class="div1"`).

And it looks like your code works as expected.

```css
div.div1 {
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: Candara;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     width: auto;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <b>Text here</b>
  </div>
</body>
```